# Prepared Statement in PHP MVC

Tags: php, select, prepared-statement

I am trying to create a simple forum in a MVC architecture.
This is my **database setup** (the relevant part):
Table: forum_categories

```
`forum_categories` (
`cat_id` INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`cat_title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`cat_desc` TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`),
UNIQUE KEY (`cat_title`)
```

Table: forum_topics

```
`forum_topics` (
`topic_id` INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`cat_id` INT(8) NOT NULL COMMENT 'foreign key with forum_categories table',
`user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'foreign key with users table',
`topic_title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`topic_desc` TEXT NOT NULL, 
`topic_date` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`topic_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`cat_id`) REFERENCES forum_categories (`cat_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

**Example** of the functionality, I would like to achieve:
Category 1 has cat_id = 1
Category 2 has cat_id = 2

Topic 1 has cat_id = 1
Topic 2 has cat_id = 2

Now when category 1 is selected I just want topic 1 to show.
If category2 is selected I just want topic 2 to show.
This prepared SQL statement achieves that:

```
PREPARE stmnt FROM 
    'SELECT * 
    FROM forum_categories fc
    JOIN forum_topics ft ON fc.cat_id = ft.cat_id
    WHERE fc.cat_id = ?
    ORDER BY ft.topic_date DESC';

SET @a = 1;
EXECUTE stmnt USING @a;
```

My **Problem**: I would like to move this functionality into my PHP MVC structure.
Here is my attempt, which does not work (it shows all topics in all categories).
Controller

```
/**
* Show all the topics in the chosen category
*/
public function showForumTopics()
{
    $topic_model = $this->loadModel('Forum');
    $this->view->forum_topics = $topic_model->getForumTopics();
    $this->view->render('forum/viewTopics');
}
```

Model

```
/**
* Gets an array that contains all the forum topics in the database.
* Each array element is an object, containing a specific topic's data.
* @return array All the forum topics
*/
public function getForumTopics($cat_id)
{
     $sql = 'SELECT * FROM forum_categories fc JOIN forum_topics ft ON fc.cat_id = ft.cat_id WHERE fc.cat_id = :cat_id ORDER BY ft.topic_date DESC';
     $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
     $query->execute(array(':cat_id' => $cat_id));

     return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

View

```
if ($this->forum_topics) {
            foreach($this->forum_topics as $key => $value) {
                echo '<p><strong>Title:</strong>' . $value->topic_title . '</p>';
                echo '<p><strong>Description:</strong> ' . $value->topic_desc . '</p>';
                echo '<p><strong>Author:</strong> ' . $value->topic_author . '</p>';
                echo '<p><strong>Date:</strong> ' . $value->topic_date . '</p>';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'No forum topics.';
        }
```

Help would be highly appreciated! Thank you!!

Comment: Does $cat_id have the value you expect it to?

Comment: No! That is my problem. I would like the value of $cat_id to be set by which category I select.

Comment: How are you modifying `$cat_id`?

Comment: Oh yeh I see, your not passing it into the getForumTopics() method, where does it originally come from? GET / POST?

Comment: When I for example save a topic in category 1 (cat_id = 1), the topic is going to have the foreign key cat_id = 1. Afterward I do not modify it at all.

Comment: That might very well be the problem. I thought it is coming from the SQL Select query? Sorry I am really new to this.

Comment: where does the category id come from? what MVC framework are you using? as it stands, this code **can't** work, since you are not passing the the required `$cat_id` parameter

Comment: I am using a MVC Framework by Panique -> https://github.com/panique/php-login  How could I get the $cat_id parameter from the database and then pass it on?

Comment: the parameter does not come from the database, it goes to the database, from the HTTP request (the MVC framework).

Comment: It is not possible to get the cat_id value out of both tables and just show the topics in which the cat_id value is equal to each other? Can I not do something like GET_['cat_id'] and then compare it to the cat_id in the other table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, your page http://example.com/?cat_id=2
Your code should be like this

Controller

```
public function showForumTopics()
{
    $default_category = 1;
    $topic_model = $this->loadModel('Forum');
    $cat_id = isset($_GET['cat_id']) ? $_GET['cat_id'] : $default_category;
    $this->view->forum_topics = $topic_model->getForumTopics($cat_id);
    $this->view->render('forum/viewTopics');
}
```

Model

```
public function getForumTopics($cat_id) {
     $sql = 'SELECT * FROM forum_categories fc JOIN forum_topics ft ON fc.cat_id = ft.cat_id WHERE fc.cat_id = :cat_id ORDER BY ft.topic_date DESC';
     $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
     $query->execute(array(':cat_id' => $cat_id));

     return $query->fetchAll(); }
```

View

```
if ($this->forum_topics) {
            foreach($this->forum_topics as $key => $value) {
                echo '<p><strong>Title:</strong>' . $value->topic_title . '</p>';
                echo '<p><strong>Description:</strong> ' . $value->topic_desc . '</p>';
                echo '<p><strong>Author:</strong> ' . $value->topic_author . '</p>';
                echo '<p><strong>Date:</strong> ' . $value->topic_date . '</p>';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'No forum topics.';
        }
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! Unfortunately, I cannot use the URL (http://example.com/?cat_id=2) because I change it in .htaccess file, due to the MVC structure (it is going to be http://example.com/forum/showForumTopics/ no  matter the id). But this is much closer to an answer than anything else... Thank you for your effort!!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your backend requires and ID to pull the specific category (and via the join, the correct topic). In your DB Query, you are looking for it here: `WHERE fc.cat_id = ?`

Your `getForumTopics($cat_id)` function also requires the ID to pass into that prepared statement. Problem is you aren't passing any ID into that function when you call it:

`$this->view->forum_topics = $topic_model->getForumTopics();`

So without anything coming through, your function is now broken and should be throwing an error. You have two options at this point:

1. Provide an ID from the page, through the controller to your function (hint, you'll have to add it to the URL like @kringeltorte suggested so the page knows what to load!)
2. Make a backup that lists all topics when no specific category is chosen. You'd do that with something like this in your function definition:

   ```
   // Specifying the backup option null here, for when there is no ID passed
   public function getForumTopics($cat_id = null) { 

       // Simple check for an ID
       if ($id) {

            // Run the code you had before
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM forum_categories fc JOIN forum_topics ft ON fc.cat_id = ft.cat_id WHERE fc.cat_id = :cat_id ORDER BY ft.topic_date DESC';
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute(array(':cat_id' => $cat_id));

            return $query->fetchAll(); }

       } else {

           // Otherwise, do the same thing as above but without a WHERE clause
       }

   }
   ```